# C# Generate Azure Table Storage ConnectionString

Tags: c#, .net, azure, connection-string, azure-storage

I want to generate connectionString for azure table storage using azure subscriptionId and azureApiKey.

I found the following Microsoft library: https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/tree/master
 but can't understand how can I generate connectionString here. I can't even find appropriate method for it.

Do I need additional data to generate ConnectionString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need additional data to generate ConnectionString?

**Preparation:**

1.Registry an app in the Azure AD and create service principal for accessing the resource. More detail please refer to the [document](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

2.Prepare the authentication file with the content as following format. The values can be got from the step 1.

```
subscription=########-####-####-####-############
client=########-####-####-####-############
key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
tenant=########-####-####-####-############
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/
```

3.Install the libraries [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/) in the project

**Demo Code:**

```
var credFile = @"auth file path"; // example: c:\tom\auth.txt
var keyName = "key1";
var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription(); 
var storageAccount = azure.StorageAccounts.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, storageName);
var key = storageAccount.RegenerateKey(keyName);
var connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName={storageAccount.Name};AccountKey={key.FirstOrDefault()?.Value}";
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out now

Comment: Thanks Tom for brief and excellent information. But I need to create StorageAccount on runtime. could you please provide the sample for this?

Comment: `var accounts = azure.StorageAccounts.Define("storageName").WithRegion("region").WithExistingResourceGroup("resourcegroupname").Create();`

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to generate it, you can just go in to the azure portal and just create a storage account any copy the connections string:

[image]

But, if you want to generate it, you can just fill this string with your account name and key:
"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={yourAccountName};AccountKey={yourAccountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

If you want to use the .net library, you can find the example here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-manage-storage-accounts

Comment: Okay, but I need to generate connectionString on runtime only using AzureSubscriptionId and AzureApiKey and save it in another collection. What's the solution for this?